# Redundant code in a loop

Tags: c, algorithm, loops

I have a list:

```
id num1 ...
-----------
 1  123 ...
 1  456 ...
 2  789 ...
 2  666 ...
```

And would like to create an object array based on it:

```
{ 1, [123, 456], [...] },
{ 2, [789, 666], [...] }
```

Here is my pseudo code:

```
int previous_id = -1;
array a1 = null; // B
array a2 = null; // B
array a3 = null; // B
array a4 = null; // B
while (++c) { // c is a pointer pointing to the list
  if (c.id != previous_id && previous_id != -1) {
    j[i++].id = previous_id;   // A
    j[i++].data1 = a1;         // A
    j[i++].data2 = a2;         // A
    j[i++].data3 = a3;         // A
    j[i++].data4 = a4;         // A
    a1 = null;   // B
    a2 = null;   // B
    a3 = null;   // B
    a4 = null;   // B
  }
  a1.add(c.num1);
  a2.add(c.num2);
  a3.add(c.num3);
  a4.add(c.num4);
  previous_id = c.id;
}
j[i++].id = previous_id;   // A
j[i++].data1 = a1;         // A
j[i++].data2 = a2;         // A
j[i++].data3 = a3;         // A
j[i++].data4 = a4;         // A
```

It is working but with some redundant code, i.e. A and B

Is it possible to merge them to make it more concise and clear?

Comment: Why do you call it redundant? If the part of code is not clear then add a comment for the statements. Do you mean inefficient?

Comment: Depends on the semantics of `j[i++].data = a` in your implementation language - if it keeps a "live" reference to the object, such that subsequent `a.add(c.num)` calls will be observed in that `data` member, then you can switch things around. OTOH if `data` takes a copy of `a` as it is at the time and never observes updates, I can't think of a way offhand

Comment: @AbhishekBansal updated my question. Yes, maybe it is not redundant, it just looks not concise enough. When I finished my code I feel there should be some way to merge `A` and/or `B` together, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: How does that 'work' if you keep incrementing `i` before setting up the entire object and try to use a `null` array (unless you meant an empty one)?

Comment: Standard approach to get rid of repeating code blocks: extract a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you could do to improve clarity of your code, if that's the objective.

Rather than using different names, use indexes.

"array" is not defined, so I guess it's a table of something. You could have something like :

```
  #define NB_ARRAYS 4
  array myArrays[NB_ARRAYS];
```

This way, you will be able to loop through your arrays, and eventually change the number of arrays anytime in the future.

The good think is that you no longer need to list separately your arrays, a single loop is enough. Hence :

```
    a1 = null;   // B
    a2 = null;   // B
    a3 = null;   // B
    a4 = null;   // B
```

becomes

```
    { int i; for (i=0; i<NB_ARRAYS; i++) myArrays[i] = NULL; }
```

You may complain that this is no better than the first version, but you can actually hide this complexity behind a macro :

```
    #define INIT_ARRAYS(a) { int i; for (i=0; i<NB_ARRAYS; i++) a[i] = NULL; }
```

or even better, behind an inline function :

```
    static inline void initArrays(array* a) { int i; for (i=0; i<NB_ARRAYS; i++) a[i] = NULL; }
```

So it becomes :

```
    initArrays(myArrays);
```

which is much clearer.

Reusing the same principles, it would lead your code to something like this :

```
    int previous_id = -1;
    initArrays(myArrays);

    while (++c) 
    { // c is a pointer pointing to the list
       addToArrays(myArrays, c);
       if (c.id != previous_id && previous_id != -1 || c.islast() ) 
       {
           j[i++].id = previous_id;   // A
           setArrays(j, i, myArrays); i+=NB_ARRAYS;
           if (!c.islast()) { initArrays(myArrays); }
       }
    }
    previous_id = c.id;
```

which should be easier to read, and therefore easier to maintain.

Also : try to use easier to read variables. In this example, I don't know what c, i or j stand for (nor where they are defined). It doesn't cost much to use 5-6 characters to properly name them, and really help code maintainance.

Comment: Good advice. Actually there are no such a1 a2 ... in my code, they already named such as `phoneNumber`, `familyName`, `honorificPrefix` ... and c is actually a `Cursor cursor` and it needs to be initialized by `getContentResolver().query(...)` and `++c` is `cursor.moveToNext()`, those arrays are actually JSONObjects, strings and JSONArray, they need to be initialized by different ways, such as `new JSONObject(someString)` or `new JSONArray(object)`, ... I just want to focus on how to improve the structure of code itself so wrote a simple pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit too pseudo-code-y for my liking - suggestions are very dependent on what your actual implementation looks like. However, I'll give some ideas.

**For the `A` part:**

`struct`'s in C will allow you to do something like:

```
someStruct temp = {previous_id, a1, a2, a3, a4};
j[i++] = temp;
```

**For the `B` part:**

I assume `null` actually refers to an empty array, rather than a `null` array, and you possibly have a fixed-length array with a separate length indicator for the populated length.

You can always have an array of lengths, and a 2D main array instead, and `memset` the entire length array to `0` rather than setting them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way to merge `A` and avoid necessarily resetting `B`:

```
int previous_id = -1;
array a1 = null; // B
array a2 = null; // B
array a3 = null; // B
array a4 = null; // B
while (++c) { // c is a pointer pointing to the list
  a1.add(c.num1);
  a2.add(c.num2);
  a3.add(c.num3);
  a4.add(c.num4);
  if (c.id != previous_id && previous_id != -1
      || c.islast() ) {
    j[i++].id = previous_id;   // A
    j[i++].data1 = a1;         // A
    j[i++].data2 = a2;         // A
    j[i++].data3 = a3;         // A
    j[i++].data4 = a4;         // A
    if (!c.islast()) {
        a1 = null;   // B
        a2 = null;   // B
        a3 = null;   // B
        a4 = null;   // B
    }
  }
  previous_id = c.id;
}
```